# Sum Two Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm suppose to add the sum of the votes per state and the sum per candidate of this two dimensional array.

These are the requirements:

- Modify the program so that the total votes cast per state are shown
  (I.e., add a column to each row summing the total votes cast for all 
  candidates per state)
- Modify the program so that the total votes per candidate are shown (I.e., add a last row showing total votes received for all three columns of votes)

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  // TODO code application logic here
  File election = new File("voting_2008.txt");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(election);

  String[] states = new String[51];
  int[][]votes = new int[51][4];
  int[] Totalbystate = new int[votes.length];

  for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
  {
      states[s] = sc.nextLine();
  }

  for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
  {
      for(int s=0; s < 51; s++)
      {
          votes[s][c] = sc.nextInt(); 
      }

  }
  Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
  fmt.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "State", "Obama", "McCain", "Other", "Total by state");
  System.out.println(fmt);
  for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
  {
     fmt = new Formatter();
     fmt.format("%20s", states[s]);
     System.out.print(fmt);
     for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
     {
         fmt = new Formatter();
         fmt.format("%12d", votes[s][c]);
         System.out.print(fmt);

     }
     int sum =0;
     for(int row=0; row < votes.length; row++)
     {              
         for (int col=0; col < votes[row].length; col++)
         {
            sum = sum + votes[row][col];
         }
     }
         fmt = new Formatter();
         fmt.format("%21d", Totalbystate) ;  
     System.out.println();
  }
  ```

Comment: Umm.. So, What's the question?

Comment: the sum isn't working. when I compiled, I get an error    
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I
             Alabama      813479     1266546       19794 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
 at small_program_07.Small_program_07.main(Small_program_07.java:69)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @user1663414: Look at exactly what the exception says. It's got nothing to do with the summation itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with summation, and everything to do with formatting. Just *this* code will demonstrate the same problem:

```
int[] values = new int[10];
new Formatter().format("%21d", values);
```

It's not clear what you expected this to do, but I suspect you *actually* want to either do something like:

```
// Please change your variable names to follow Java conventions
fmt = new Formatter(System.out);
for (int value : Totalbystate) {
    fmt.format("%21d", value);
}
```

Alternatively, specify a single format string such as `"%21d%21d%21d%21d%21d"` (etc) and pass in an `Integer[]` instead of an `int[]`.

Additionally, you should fix your program's indentation - it's unnecessarily confusing at the moment.